# Tool for modeling MariaDB bases

Tags: modeling, mariadb

For a moment I use MySQL Workbench to model my MariaDB bases and manage my changes with the synchronize method of MySQL Workbench.
It is very convenient.

But like MySQL Workbench is not designed for MariaDB, some new options of MariaDB are not possible like virtual columns.
So my question is simple. What tool do you use to model your MariaDB ?
To can synchronize the changes directement is very convenient, there is a tool like MySQL Workbench dedicated to MariaDB ?

Thanks for your help !